# Does IRC have user-modes that are channel specific, especially for away status?

Tags: irc

I'm writing an IRC bot that hangs out in lots of channels, but in some of those channels I want to mark the bot as muted/away/quiet. I've done this via code - stopping the bot sending messages to those channels, but I'd like a way for other IRC users to determine if the bot it silent in that channel.

A traditional way of doing this on IRC has been setting your nick to botname_, or botname|afk, but obviously that has effect in all channels so it's not going to work on a per-channel basis.

The bot is an OP, otherwise I think minus voice (-v) might have worked - I can't get the bot to take voice away from itself, can I? Is there another mode or trick I could use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* way to do this, would be with the `/away` command.

It doesn't provide immediate, visible indication of the current status of the bot, but anybody that `/msg`s or `/whois`s the bot will see the message.

Failing that, depending on what network you're on, the bot can use:

```
/msg ChanServ VOICE #channel botname
```

Which will cause `ChanServ` to voice the bot, providing they have the necessary access levels, or are on the VOP list *(see /msg ChanServ help VOP)*